# How do I prevent the M3 Compose ModalBottomSheet from detaching when flinging inner LazyRow content?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet

I have a `ModalBottomSheet` and within I have a `LazyColumn` with a list of items. When I scroll quickly up or down, i.e. fling, that `LazyColumn` content, then the bottom sheet briefly detaches from the bottom or the top (depending on scroll direction). I want to remove this behaviour so that my `ModalBottomSheet` is firmly stuck to the bottom and the top (it's a full screen bottom sheet).

Does anyone have any idea how to achieve that? :)

I'm using the currently newest bottom sheet from this dependency:
`androidx.compose.material3:material3-android:1.2.0-alpha02`

This is how it looks like:
[image]

I've remove a lot of the content code, but in general the bottom sheet content is like this:

```
@Composable
fun BottomSheetContent() {
    Column(modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                .weight(1f)
        ) {
            GenresSection(
                selectedGenres = selectedGenres,
            )
            
        }
        ResetAllAndApplyFilterButtonsRow(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(vertical = 16.dp, horizontal = 16.dp)
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun GenresSection(
    selectedGenres: List<Genre>,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = modifier.height(400.dp),
    ) {
        items(selectedGenres) { genre ->
            GenreChoiceRow(
                text = genre.name,
                modifier = Modifier.animateItemPlacement()
            )
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried an AI suggested approach of attaching a nestedScrollConnection where I adjusted the onPostFling behaviour to return 0 Velocity, so it wouldn't return any Velocity after flinging to the parent, but that didn't help. This was suggested by the phind.com AI:

```
val nestedScrollConnection = remember {
    object : NestedScrollConnection {
        override suspend fun onPostFling(consumed: Velocity, available: Velocity): Velocity {
            return super.onPostFling(consumed, Velocity.ZERO)
        }

        override suspend fun onPreFling(available: Velocity): Velocity {
            return super.onPreFling(available)
        }
    }
}

LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier.nestedScroll(nestedScrollConnection)
) {
    // Your scrollable content here
}
```

Comment: I think it's a bug in the `ModalBottomSheet`, it used to not behave like that in previous versions. I also experiencing the same issue in latest `ModalBottomSheetLayout` (material 2)

Comment: I've found that issue in the issue tracker and upvoted it. Hopefully they'll address it soon. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/201628457

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is fixed in

```
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.3.0-alpha02")
```

Answer (score 0):

i try this

```kotlin
LazyVerticalGrid(columns = GridCells.Fixed(2), flingBehavior = flingBehavior) {
                        videoTempState.value.pagConfigBean?.videoTempList?.let { it ->
                            items(it, key = { it?.uuid ?: "" }) {
                                Box(
                                    modifier = Modifier
                                        .fillMaxWidth()
                                        .height(200.dp)
                                ) {
                                    AndroidView(factory = {
                                        PAGView(it)
                                    }, update = {

                                    })
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

emphasis is setting fling

```kotlin
private val flingBehavior = object : FlingBehavior {
    override suspend fun ScrollScope.performFling(initialVelocity: Float): Float {
        return 0F
    }
}
```